# how to close CafePay Printer Driver on windows

Tags: printers

Cafepay Virtual Printer Driver cannot be closed from the tray icon, it's got something to do with the registry, how do I close it and remove it from auto startup?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix for that, Officially released from the CafePay company.

1. Open task manager and end process any cafepay-printer-driver.exe that you see
2. Delete the folder from C drive
3. Extract and run the new CafePay application
4. Now you have control from the Tray icon

If the problem persists, call Qioo sales support. They will find a way to uninstall CafePay!